# assign one ArrayList string value to another ArrayList element

Tags: android, arraylist

I want to store two different `ArrayList` values in one array list.
Here is my main array list.

```
ArrayList<bean> finalArray = new ArrayList();  //main arraylist
ArrayList<String> start = new ArrayList();  //string arraylist
ArrayList<String> end= new ArrayList();  //string arraylist

bean.class

public class testbean {
    String start;

    public String getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(String start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public String getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public void setEnd(String end) {
        this.end = end;
    }

    String end;
}
```

`String` values are stored in the start and end string `ArrayList`.

So how to assign start string and end string `ArrayList` values to main `ArrayList` values(testbean.setStart || testbean.end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do one thing Create a constuctor testbean class and assign your value to it when you initialize it.

```
 public testbean(String start, String end) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
}
```